# How to write a conf file for Java?

Tags: java, config, processing

I am writing a code in Processing 2.0 and have embedded it in Java environment using Eclipse. The code has many parameters which I frequently need to access in all classes. Below is the example of parameters I work with in the program.

```
imgPath = "~/data/img/A.svg";
dataFile = "~/data/log.csv";
N = 64.4;
S = 52.0;
```

Most of the parameters are file directory paths or few global parameters. I want to create a config file that can hold all the above parameters which I can included in my Java program. A typical usecase would be when I hand over this program to someone else and he just changes the parameters in the conf file and rest works fine.

Can someone please give me an example of a conf file for Java and how to include it in the program?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use standard [Java Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) unless you have a reason to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Write .conf file outside of java program and only take conf file from java.

Actually conf file is not different from txt file for java.

Comment: I didn't really understood that. Can you give an example with above parameters?

Comment: open a file in notepad, and call it `myConfig.conf`, then fill it with whatever you need, then open that file with java and use it as configuration file.
Configuration file is not different from normal file in java